# Any difference between node commands 'cordova ionic' and 'ionic'? Which command need to use?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, ionic-framework

Is there any difference between node commands `npm install -g cordova ionic` and `npm install -g ionic`.

Which command do I need to use to build a ionic project. The documentation given in [ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) and [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ionic) are different.

Comment: This question makes no sense. They are two different packages, which don't depend on each other.

Comment: See the documentation given in [ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) and [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ionic). Which command do I need to use to build a ionic project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's get the clarifications out of the way:

1. Cordova and ionic are names of packages that you install with the npm install command
2. The -g flag is used to install the packages globally and be available throughout the system.

Now, to answer your question: The documentation in npmjs for ionic assumes cordova is already installed and provides the command to install ionic-cli

If you try to run

```
ionic start myapp tabs
```

without having cordova installed only ionic it will throw a "Package missing" error.

The documentation in the [ionicframework](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) website mentions that the cordova package needs to be installed to use the ionic-cli successfully.

Why does ionic need cordova? Well because ionic-cli uses cordoba-cli, and when starting a new ionic project it first initialises a cordova project.

Therefore to start an ionic project, you need `npm install -g ionic cordova` and then `ionic start myapp {templateName}`

Hope everything is clear now!